# How can I convert this Dataset to List

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, associations

I'm very new to Mathematica, I'm having the following dataset structure :
[image]

I want to get data in the following way so that I plot it to TimeSeries using joined/left[1/0] as v and ts as time:

```
{vinayak, {joined,left},{1588139224312,1588144304424}},
{vishal, {joined,left},{1588139224312,1588144304424}},
{yasser, {joined,left,joined,left,joined,left,joined,left}, {..}},{...}
```

Any help will be appreciated, thanks :)

Comment: Please include a small sample of the dataset in the question. The key to the solution is `GroupBy`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way to do it

```
dataset = {
    <|"user" -> "vinayak", "event" -> "joined", "ts" -> RandomInteger[10]|>,
    <|"user" -> "vinayak", "event" -> "left", "ts" -> RandomInteger[10]|>,
    <|"user" -> "vishal", "event" -> "joined", "ts" -> RandomInteger[10]|>,
    <|"user" -> "vishal", "event" -> "left", "ts" -> RandomInteger[10]|>,
    <|"user" -> "yasser", "event" -> "joined", "ts" -> RandomInteger[10]|>,
    <|"user" -> "yasser", "event" -> "left", "ts" -> RandomInteger[10]|>,
    <|"user" -> "yasser", "event" -> "joined", "ts" -> RandomInteger[10]|>,
    <|"user" -> "yasser", "event" -> "left", "ts" -> RandomInteger[10]|>,
    <|"user" -> "yasser", "event" -> "joined", "ts" -> RandomInteger[10]|>,
    <|"user" -> "yasser", "event" -> "left", "ts" -> RandomInteger[10]|>} // Dataset;

dataset[GroupBy[Key["user"]] /* Values, Merge[Identity]] // Normal // Values // 
  MapAt[First, #, {All, 1}] &

(*
{{"vinayak", {"joined", "left"}, {5, 5}},
 {"vishal", {"joined", "left"}, {0, 3}},
 {"yasser", {"joined", "left", "joined", "left", "joined", "left"}, {10, 3, 5, 6, 8, 10}}}
*)
```

Comment: Thank you! It works :)